# strictReceivePaths not the same as strictSendPaths when reversed

Tags: horizon, path-payment, paths

I would assume that the `strictReceivePaths`  would be the same as `strictSendPaths` when reversed. For example, query these:

`strictReceivePaths`:

```
https://horizon.stellar.org/paths/strict-receive?destination_asset_type=credit_alphanum4&destination_asset_issuer=GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX&destination_asset_code=USD&destination_amount=.0008&source_assets=native
```

result:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "records": [
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112649",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "0.0008000",
        "path": []
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112740",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "0.0008000",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "ULT",
            "asset_issuer": "GC76RMFNNXBFDSJRBXCABWLHXDK4ITVQSMI56DC2ZJVC3YOLLPCKKULT"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "CNY",
            "asset_issuer": "GAREELUB43IRHWEASCFBLKHURCGMHE5IF6XSE7EXDLACYHGRHM43RFOX"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112822",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "0.0008000",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "ULT",
            "asset_issuer": "GC76RMFNNXBFDSJRBXCABWLHXDK4ITVQSMI56DC2ZJVC3YOLLPCKKULT"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "CNY",
            "asset_issuer": "GAREELUB43IRHWEASCFBLKHURCGMHE5IF6XSE7EXDLACYHGRHM43RFOX"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "USD",
            "asset_issuer": "GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112958",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "0.0008000",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "NGNT",
            "asset_issuer": "GAWODAROMJ33V5YDFY3NPYTHVYQG7MJXVJ2ND3AOGIHYRWINES6ACCPD"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0113129",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "0.0008000",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "TDC",
            "asset_issuer": "GALZ4WFY7AUUOIIPWDO33GG22HAEC2AX7ZZ7B3MZVXBEJWDSXQECZG6R"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`strictSendPaths`:

```
https://horizon.stellar.org/paths/strict-send?source_asset_type=native&source_amount=0.0112649&destination_assets=USD:GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX
```

result:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "records": [
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112649",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "158.7136660",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "ETC",
            "asset_issuer": "GCTXRQIYWEDP6G7OXZI6IXUSIXHHSN5NKYRB3NI5J4Z7G5JMIBHLLBTC"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "USD",
            "asset_issuer": "GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112649",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "158.7136660",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "LTC",
            "asset_issuer": "GBVOL67TMUQBGL4TZYNMY3ZQ5WGQYFPFD5VJRWXR72VA33VFNL225PL5"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "XLB",
            "asset_issuer": "GAMA33LC7FK5RF4XE5HOVX456GX4VHDZUCJ7APY4TZ4IHG65ZWVXD333"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "USD",
            "asset_issuer": "GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112649",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "158.7136660",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "LINK",
            "asset_issuer": "GBDEVU63Y6NTHJQQZIKVTC23NWLQVP3WJ2RI2OTSJTNYOIGICST6DUXR"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "ETX",
            "asset_issuer": "GCEFMSNWXTALXQPRQFIXOMWJHZFDEQJBM26RGEDZUDFMU32JB6WJGRJX"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "USD",
            "asset_issuer": "GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112649",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "158.7136660",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum12",
            "asset_code": "Diglett",
            "asset_issuer": "GDKDKVEYV4TSELBCMNFFR7FAX7CYY6LYOIOR5P2LMB2T5S4N2V5A5IW6"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "ABDT",
            "asset_issuer": "GDZURZR6RZKIQVOWZFWPVAUBMLLBQGXP2K5E5G7PEOV75IYPDFA36WK4"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "USD",
            "asset_issuer": "GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "0.0112649",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USD",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX",
        "destination_amount": "158.7136660",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "MAG",
            "asset_issuer": "GAACROE4I6LRXKDKAJ4PKGQHRAU43ZDKRBBSNCVYW5TXBP4RAWO62JAH"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "GRAT",
            "asset_issuer": "GAJ7V3EMD3FRWAPBEJAP7EC4223XI5EACDZ46RFMY5DYOMCIMWEFR5II"
          },
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "USD",
            "asset_issuer": "GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Of particular note are the too-large `destination_amount`s in the `strictSendPaths` and the non-matching paths between the two.

I see no problem with the `strictReceivePaths` as I can carry out successful `pathPaymentStrictReceive` transactions with these. I, however, cannot make successful transactions with the `strictSendPaths` in `pathPaymentStrictSend` transactions and I receive the error `op_under_dest_min`, regardless of the `destMin` amount I enter, whether `0.0000001` or `99999999999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We think this may be a result of [Strict-send pathfinder returns non-existent paths](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/1856), which is fixed in [Horizon 0.23](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/horizon-v0.23.0). Would you try the new release and report back here?

Comment: How does one try this new release? I am merely querying using my browser.

Comment: 0.23 is now up. And I confirm that the strict send paths have been fixed. I now can carry out transactions with them.